# Spring Integration(JDBC - SFTP) : Read a record, send it to SFTP and delete that record

Tags: spring-integration

I have following requirement to implement for each incoming message into our system

1. Convert incoming to to XML file and save in database
2. Read that file from data base and Send it SFTP
3. Delete the entry once File send is sucessful.

I have implemented Step-1 successfully :

```
<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter  query="insert into table_name(id, payload) values (:headers[fileName], :payload)" channel="outputChannel" jdbc-operations="jdbcTemplate">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" />
</int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

While implementing Step-2, if I read all entries together, I get the payload in List which spring-sftp doesn't support it. If read each record to and send to SFTP, its a performance problem. Any suggestion please?

```
   <int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter row-mapper="rowMapper" query="select * from table_name" channel="sftpChannel" jdbc-operations="jdbcTemplate">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" />
    </int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

How to delete the record upon file send successful?. I guess payload.delete() won't work here.

```
   <sftp:outbound-channel-adapter auto-startup="true" id="sftpOutboundAdapter" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" channel="sftpChannel" charset="UTF-8" remote-directory="${spectrum.ftp.path}" remote-filename-generator-expression="headers[fileName] + '.xml'">
    <sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.delete()" />
        </bean>
    </sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
</sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: Why not directly send it to SFTP?

Comment: If you really want single files you can always use a splitter after the content has been read, converting the list into individual items.

Comment: @ M. Deinum : Sending directly to SFTP is already in place. To have failover mechanism, we have to save these file DB and send it SFTP. I will try with splitter. Thanks.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to delete same entry from DB?

Comment: Instead of doing the intermediate insert into the database you can probably easier use a persistence `MessageStore` then try it yourself. Also what is the failover you want, when using JMS you can just use the JMS queue for that.

Comment: We don't use JMS. our goal is to convert incoming messages and send to SFTP server. If failover happens we would to like have solution to save these files into db and send it SFTP server when backup node is active.

Comment: As stated you could probably use a persistent messagestore for that, you can just attach it to your queue/channel.

Comment: Marten, move you commet to the answer. The `persistence queue` with `<transactional>` `<poller>` is really the best solution for this requirement. And yes, the message will be remove from the DB on the TX commit.